# weird errors at boot and shutdown

Tags: awk, boot, shutdown, openrc

I am running Adelie Linux, an independent distro based on musl and openRC as service manager, on a x86_64 laptop. My desktop environment is KDE Plasma 5.18. When the system is shutting down, I notice some obscure errors in rc.log. At boot:

```
rc boot logging started at Tue Sep  8 17:46:25 2020

/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: 98: printf: printf: I/O error
...
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: 98: cannot create /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/net.wlan0/tasks: Directory nonexistent
```

and at shutdown:

```
/lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh: 98: cannot create /sys/fs/cgroup/openrc/local/tasks: Directory nonexistent
* Stopping local ... [ ok ]
 * Stopping sddm ... [ ok ]
 * Bringing down interface wlan0
 *   Stopping wpa_cli on wlan0 ... [ ok ]
 *   Stopping wpa_supplicant on wlan0 ... [ ok ]
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bts.adelielinux.org/

Comment: thanks, I hit them up on their IRC channel but I couldn't get an answer